# How to start the hadoop which i just install ,rather than the former version

Tags: hadoop

I want to installed the hadoop(3.2) in my linux system which has installed the hadoop(2.7).When I execute hadoop , I can only get the information of hadoop 2.7 ,even if I change the environment variable. And the most confused thing is when I run echo $HADOOP_HOME , sometimes I can get the path of hadoop 2.7,sometimes hadoop 3.2. I hope someone can help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DovkK.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grn9M.png)

Comment: Changing `HADOOP_HOME` just changes the environment variable, not your path. If your path is based on `HADOOP_HOME` then you need to refresh your path, either by opening a new terminal or re-sourcing your shell's startup script. If your path isn't based on `HADOOP_HOME` then you need to update your path some other way.

Comment: THK , I find the answer , I change the /etc/profile , but I don't change bashrc , so the local variable make difference

Comment: You should probably change your personal shell startup rather than the system one.